# How to remove my app's old notifications from notification bar in Flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a app that give alarms(notifications with custom sounds). But notification sound doesn't work after having lot of notifications in notification bar. So I want to clear 1 hour old notifications from notification bar. Something like that...

I know how to remove all notifications in notification bar but I want to remove older notifications only in FLUTTER.
NOTE: devices running the app has android 8+

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you using flutter_local_notification package, you can remove specific notification by their id.

If you are trying to remove remote notifications presented by firebase library itself, then I don't think there is a way to detect and remove specific notifications.

Answer (score 1):

With lib [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). Simple you can use below code to remove all notification of app:

```
logoutFirebase(){
  // messaging.unsubscribeFromTopic("all");
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken();
  // call to API delete columns ft_token with id and device if need
  // this line to remove all notification
  localNotification.cancelAll();
}
```

Comment: Just use `localNotification.cancelAll();` removed all firebase old notifications